# Why aren't countries ignoring COVID-19 patents and are instead waiting for a patent waiver?

Tags: law, international-relations

Why aren't countries ignoring COVID-19 patents and are instead waiting for a patent waiver? There's already advanced discussions about a patent waiver for vaccines, so why aren't countries just ignoring the patents for now and act immediately to vaccinate as many people as possible. Is there some political mechanisms or factors I am underestimating or ignoring here?

Comment: Not waiting for a patent waiver breaks the law, no?

Comment: @Allure that sounds like the start of an answer :).

Comment: @Allure This user has been asking lots of "why does country X not do Y if international law says Y" questions.  To which the most frequent type of answer here has been "because countries are sovereign and international law only goes so far".  Now they are asking a question again, different subject, and your comment is "duh, because law says so"???

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica by 'this user' are you referring to me or to Sayaman?

Comment: @Allure Sayaman's been asking all these international law questions.  I thought that was somewhat clear in *Now **they** are asking a question again, different subject, and your comment*, but maybe not.

Comment: @Sayaman I guess the point being made is that international law does not make it easy to coerce a sovereign country to do or not do something, as has been answered to your questions before.  In this case however the sovereign country is still free to ignore agreement and laws if they want.  But it will *also* need other countries ' collaboration sooner or later on this subject and so it may not find it worthwhile to flout the rules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be a mistake to think that *only* patents and intellectual property laws are holding back vaccine production. Don't you think the current producers are expanding their production as fast as they can? Starting a new production line for these vaccines is *difficult*. It would be *even more difficult* if there was just a copy of the patent application, not the full cooperation of the people who are running the original production line.

Answer (score 5):

The covid pandemic will eventually end, and at that time being the country that just ignored patents isn't going to be a good thing. It's easy to respect agreements when things are easy, but if a country shows they are willing to break agreements when things get tough they aren't trustworthy any more. In the best case such a country just has to compensate the patent holder for damages, in a more likely scenario all future deals this country makes get worse because there is now precedent that any agreement could be ignored if it's sufficiently inconvenient.

Sticking to the agreed rules when it's hard is important, because that's when rules matter.